# How can I set the host name for a web site/web application in IIS using tfs release management client?

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, binding, release-management

I have to deploy a few sites using TFS Release Management Client, all of them in them same machine so same IIS. They will be all on port 80 but the requests are served for different host names (domains).
Using IISConfig tool, it is possible to change the port but not the host name, do you know a quick way already implemented to achieve that without creating a custom tool?

Comment: Actually I realise that the problem is not just for hostname but for the entire binding entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec02f09f-6596-46fd-a5cb-33b6a17461b8/tfs-release-management-software-creating-a-default-binding?forum=tfsbuild), it is not possible but if you scroll down there is a suggestion how to quickly work around the limitation.
Creating 2 actions

```
-Command "& { Import-Module WebAdministration; New-WebBinding -Name '__Name__' -IPAddress '__IPAddress__' -Port '__Port__' -HostHeader '__HostHeader__'   }"
```

and

```
-Command "& { Import-Module WebAdministration; Remove-WebBinding -Name '__Name__' -IPAddress '__IPAddress__' -Port '__Port__' -HostHeader '__HostHeader__' } "
```